# Having trouble understanding the equivalency of these two summations?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

How is the following true? I'm doing an expected value problem in discrete math, and during one of the steps, it makes this transition. I am confused how this is equivalent, can anyone explain it to me?

$$\sum_{i=s+1}^\infty p(i)$$=$$1-\sum_{i=0}^s p(i)$$

Comment: Do you understand why $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p(i) = \sum_{i=0}^s p(i)+\sum_{i=s+1}^\infty p(i)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the series $\sum p (i) $ convergent and its sum is $1$.

then

$$\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}p (i)=1$$
$$p (0)+p (1)+p (2)+....=$$
$$p (0)+p (1)+...p (s)+p (s+1)+...=$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^sp (i )+\sum_{i=s+1}^{+\infty}p (i) $$

thus

$$\sum_{i=s+1}^{+\infty}p (i)=1-\sum_{i=0}^sp (i) $$